# Android CameraX returns success but not saving picture

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camerax

I have implemented android camerax but its not capturing image properly, the callback returns success but the image cannot be found or viewed.

My implementation :

```
private void startCamera(){
    final ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider> cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this);
    cameraProviderFuture.addListener(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                ProcessCameraProvider provider = cameraProviderFuture.get();
                bindPreview(provider);
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this));
}

private void bindPreview(@NonNull ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider){
    Preview preview = new Preview.Builder().build();
    CameraSelector selector = new CameraSelector.Builder().requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT).build();
    ImageCapture.Builder builder = new ImageCapture.Builder();
    final ImageCapture imageCapture = builder.setTargetRotation(this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation()).build();
    preview.setSurfaceProvider(cameraView.createSurfaceProvider());
    cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this,selector,preview,imageCapture);
    btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            selfieFile = new File(getFilesDir(),"attendance.jpg");
            OutputFileOptions outputFileOptions = new OutputFileOptions.Builder(selfieFile).build();
            imageCapture.takePicture(outputFileOptions, executor, new ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onImageSaved(@NonNull ImageCapture.OutputFileResults outputFileResults) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Glide.with(CameraActivity.this).load(outputFileResults.getSavedUri()).into(capturedImage);
                            //updateUI(false);
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull ImageCaptureException exception) {

                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I have tried loading Uri.fromFile() and also tried get imageproxy instead and converted to bitmap but still having those issue. Any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [`ImageCapture.OutputFileResults.getSavedUri()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageCapture.OutputFileResults#getSavedUri())'s documentation, this method only returns a value when `ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions` is backed by MediaStore, i.e. when you use `ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(ContentResolver, Uri, ContentValues)`.

You're using `ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(File)`, meaning that you should expect to receive `null` when you call `ImageCapture.OutputFileResults.getSavedUri()`.

I'm not familiar enough with Glide, so I'm not sure why loading the image using `Uri.fromFile()` doesn't work. You can try setting the image directly on the ImageView though to see if you're misusing Glide:

```
capturedImage.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(selfieFile))
```